# Как развернуть EJB

Tags: java-ee, glassfish, ejb

Прочитал книгу по java EE и решил попрактикоаться...
Набросал пару компонентов ejb и понимаю что я не знаю как его развернуть что бы воспользоваться. В теории знаю что их суть в удобной работе с бизнес логикой, их просто инджектить с помощью JNDI, JTA и куча всего...
Но как мне протетстировать и развернуть его в intelijIJdea.
Вопросы следующие:

1. Как поместить ear в glassfish? (как я понял для запуска нужно его связать ear с сервером приложений)
2. Как узнать или задать jndi если собираешься пользоваться компонентом удаленно на другой машине.

Comment: а вы уверены то что эти знания вам всё ещё пригодятся?

Comment: @Komdosh, думаю да.